# php-fpm doesn't work with nginx rewrites

Tags: nginx, php, rewrite, php-fpm

I am trying to rewrite to a PHP file in nginx without changing the URL, but php-fpm isn't processing the file and all I get is a 500.

If I remove the rewrite and visit the file directly, it works, so the .php file is not wrong.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/example.com/public_html;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    index index.html index.php;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

    location ~ ^/InfoCenter/api/.*$ {
        rewrite "/InfoCenter/api/(.*)" /InfoCenter/api/index.php last;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~/\.htaccess {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your location for InfoCenter is also catching the place you're rewriting to, as it's matching the regex again. i.e. Your users will be rewritten to `/InfoCenter/api/index.php` and then just get snagged into the same location. and then never sent to PHP ever.

Try changing the PHP location to be:

```
location ^~ .*\.php$ {
    ...
}
```

The change of location to regex prefix will give it precedence over the other location.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a regular expression in the `/InfoCenter/api` location. You can use:

```
location /InfoCenter/api {
    try_files /InfoCenter/api/index.php;
}
```

This way you will avoid the issue of matching the `/InfoCenter` path again. It is also slightly faster to do a prefix match than a regular expression match.

Also, `try_files` is a simpler way to forward all requests with that prefix to the `index.php` file. It also doesn't actually rewrite the URL, which is part of the problem in your original approach.

Comment: The problem is that I am accessing /InfoCenter/api/weather/, and index.php depends on the URL.

Comment: Your `rewrite` on the original question forwarded all requests to `/InfoCenter/api/index.php`. Please clarify your exact use case in your question.